# How do you create a simple multiline batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found myself having to run the same commands one after another on Windows 7 from a DOS prompt. So I put the commands in a file, one per line and then named the file buildWindows.bat, but when I run it it only runs the first line (successfully) and the exits.
This is the batch file (note build refers to another batch file build.bat)

```
build
Build copylatestbuild
C:\Apps\Code\IzPack5beta11\bin\compile C:\Code\Jaikoz\src\installer_windows\install.xml -o C:\Code\Jaikoz\target\installer\windows\\install.jar -b C:\Code\Jaikoz\src\installer_windows 
C:\Apps\Code\IzPack5beta11\bin\compile C:\Code\Jaikoz\src\installer_windows\install64.xml -o C:\Code\Jaikoz\target\installer\windows\install64.jar -b C:\Code\Jaikoz\src\installer_windows 
C:\Apps\Code\IzPack5beta11\bin\compile C:\Code\Jaikoz\src\installer_linux\install.xml  -o C:\Code\Jaikoz\target\installer\linux\install.jar -b C:\Code\Jaikoz\src\installer_linux 
build zipinstallers
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please add the content of your batch file to the question

Comment: What you did seems to be correct. Please provide more information. What are the commands?

Comment: Done and expanded, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that `build.bat` is another batch file. Then you should use `CALL` to run it, or else it "replaces" the current batch file instead of returning to it.

Comment: I like this term: "it replaces". I used to call _Overlay_ a Batch file called from another one with no `CALL` command.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
build
```

to

```
call build
```

and it should work as expected. Otherwise exiting build.bat will also exit the calling batch file.